# Multi-part Questions with Bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty

I am still new to StackExchange, but have found myself addicted. I am not sure why, but the reputation points and bounties really do help in getting a question answered... I LOVE it!

I have a multi-part, rather a situational question with a bounty - [Require min. dimensions for Featured Image? Dimensions on Media Library Tab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46930/require-min-dimensions-for-featured-image-dimensions-on-media-library-tab) - Essentially, I set up the question with the situation and reasons for each situation, as well as mentioning additional resources I have used to accomplish tasks/needs for parts of the situation.

The main (most important) part of the mulit-part question has been answered, however, I am afraid that if I award the bounty, the final part of the question will go unanswered.

I have thought about splitting the final part into a new question, but again, I fear it will go unanswered, plus that would mean the situation which has been presented will be broken up and not all together, nice and tidy.

What should I do? and Why?

Comment: I see now you have a history of overly complex questions. Stop it, please!

Comment: I suppose that is one of my "problems" when it comes to online Q&A sites, forums, etc. As a business major, I think of a situation, then try to think of all possible problems which may occur from the situation. Then, I try to work the entire situation as one (all-encompassing) problem, rather than many small problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide whether the bounty is applicable to either all or part of your question and if its "part" then define which part and award the bounty accordingly.

The latter part of your question doesn't seem out of reach either. I can think of a possible solution already...

I wouldn't agonize of it and award the bounty to the person who contributed the greatest portion of help to your answer. Its the right thing to do (IMO).

Comment: Thanks. I figured I should award the bounty to the "most important" part, as it appears others are also interested in the solution to the "most important" part. Should I split the questions or leave it as it is?

Comment: I'd personally leave the question as is, unless you get no glory and the bounty period expires which you need to award the bounty then start another question if you are in need. However I think I have a solution for you anyway or at least will be willing to help you work toward a solution...

Comment: Ok. I greatly appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 6):

In short, you should not be asking multi-part questions like this.

The question you linked is really 2 different questions:

1. Require minimum image dimensions
2. Display image dimensions in the Media Library.

I would recommend awarding the bounty for the answer to the *first* question and opening a second, *separate* question for part 2.

Comment: +1. The very concept of a "multi-part" question is contrary to the purpose of WPSE. [Per the FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), questions should be "*practical, answerable... [and] reasonably scoped*"

Comment: Ok, thanks. I suppose that is one of my "problems" when it comes to online Q&A sites, forums, etc. As a business major, I think of a situation, then try to think of all possible problems which may occur from the situation. Then, I try to work the entire situation as one (all-encompassing) problem, rather than many small problems.

Comment: It's definitely a learning process.  No worries.

Comment: +1 to the learning process. Part of the learning process, though, is to learn how the site is intended to work. The FAQ, to which I linked earlier, is the first step in that process. Relevant to your previous comment, I'll quote verbatim from the "What not to ask" section: "***You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.***" As intellectually interesting it may be to consider all theoretical scenarios, those considerations don't translate into good, useful questions for a site like WPSE.

Answer (score 3):

It is not very good practice to combine multiple loosely (as in one can be done without another logically and in code) related questions.

At moment your issue is essentially "how do I motivate answers to two questions with one bounty". You can stall with bounty (you still have days left) just so question stays featured, but in the end I'd recommend awarding to answer to important part of question and asking about other aspects separately.

Comment: Thanks. My intention was not initially to offer a bounty, just complete a set of tasks to reach the outcome of, "force user to add a featured image with minimum dimensions." It wasn't until after that I discovered the bounty system. I suppose my thought process was that was the question and the multiple questions were steps in completing the goal.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see with your current question: The whole picture is vague. Create a GitHub repository where we can see the whole code to understand what is missing.

When I can download and install a plugin, I see the missing parts much better. And contributing to a public plugin is more fun. :)

Right now everybody has to collect the pieces, stick them together and fiddle around just to reach the state from where the answer starts.
Make answering easy to get good solutions.